# Detect objects in an image in Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, opencv

I need help creating a Python code that processes an image, detects its elements, crops them, and saves them.

I programmed this code:

```
import cv2

image_path = "img.png"

image = cv2.imread(image_path)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret, mask = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)


for cnt in contours:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 0, 255), 2)

cv2.imwrite(image_path, image)
```

But it does not fully detect the object, it only detects about 50% of it approximately.

[image: image example]

Is there a way to make it detect the object completely based on color or any other method?

I have tried multiple codes from various sources, but none of them succeeded.

Comment: Are you trying to detect the two major objects or all the parts of the two objects?

Comment: @fmw42 - Detect the two major objects only

Comment: You could try a little horizontal morphology close to fill the black separations, but not so much as to connect the two major parts.

Comment: @fmw42 - Yes I am trying to do that.

Comment: "Is there a way to make it detect the object completely based on color or any other method?" do you need this to work strictly on the given image, or to extend to other similar images?

Comment: @Him - Yes, there is a way, but I don't know how.